# bundle install error for system_timer 1.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

9.3 and every time i try "bundle install" it starts ok then give me this error...

An error occurred while installing system_timer (1.2.4), and
Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install system_timer -v '1.2.4'` succeeds
before bundling.

when i try to run system_timer it says...

sudo gem install system_timer
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing system_timer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: whats your ruby version?

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 rails 3.1.4 and gem 1.3.7

Comment: ruby 1.8.7, rails 3.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gemfile.rb:

```
platform :ruby_18 do
  gem 'system_timer', '1.2.4'
end
```

Run :

```
bundle install
```

Moreover SystemTimer is only a patch for ruby 1.8's threading system. So, there is no need to have it for `ruby > 1.9.3`

Comment: thank you i commented it out and it worked....now i am getting this  error    $ bundle exec rake db:reset
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `configure' for Rhoconnect:Module

Comment: Thank you. it looks if you're building a gem that is rails specific, you need to manually require your dependencies.